# discord.js question. how do i make the bot give a different response to one command?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, discord.js

So I have the command `-joke` I want the bot to give a random response to that command.
How do I add it to this code:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'joke',
description: "tells a joke",
execute(message, args) {
   message.channel.send('Why do we tell actors to break a leg? Because every 
   play has a cast');
 }
}
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array with jokes:

```
const jokes = ["Joke1", "Joke2", "Joke3"];
```

and get a joke from the array at a random index:

```
const randJoke = jokes[Math.floor(Math.random() * jokes.length)];
```

then send the random joke in the current text channel:

```
message.channel.send(randJoke);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store your jokes.

Assuming your array is called jokes:

```js
const getJoke = () => {
 return jokes[Math.floor(Math.random() * jokes.length))];
}
```

This should then get you a random one from your array. Just send the output of that function to your user